# Vue good table shows data inside cell with border

Tags: vuejs2

I am using vue good table. When I show my data, the data appears fine within the bordered table but each cell displays bordered data while I don't want my data bordered but I want my table bordered.When I try to remove chang its custom cs,it also removes the table borders with cell data borders. Kindly help.Thank you

```
                    <vue-good-table

                    title="Customers Table"
                    :columns="columns"
                    :rows="rows"
                    :paginate="true"
                    :pagination-options="{
                    enabled: true,
                    mode: 'records',
                    perPage: 10,
                    position: 'bottom',
                    perPageDropdown: [10, 20, 50],
                    }"
                    :search-options="{enabled: true}"
                    :lineNumbers="true"
                   >
```

Comment: can you please share more code?

Comment: I have  not used much of my own code as I am using the default css of vue good table but still my table is as above